# How can google map consistently display need to display location?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Every time we go to google map that notification show up,. If we press cancel, and go to google map again that notification show up again.

This is my code:

```
  while (false);
    static NSDate * lastSearched = nil;

    NSDate * dNow=[NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval ti = [dNow timeIntervalSinceDate:lastSearched];
    if (ti<60) {
        return;
    }
    lastSearched =dNow;
    CLAuthorizationStatus  clAuth= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (clAuth ==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
```

That notification shows up only once.

Comment: Then what? The alert is not shown by me. The alert is shown by apple. Many times it doesn't show up.

Comment: Here, whats your problem?.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is I check if location is authorized and do not seek location if not authorized.

What I should do is demand location to start searching. That's when the alert show up.

`[singleton.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`  **triggers alerts**

If location is not authorized, then I simply shouldn't wait for update that will never be called.

What I did before:

```
CLAuthorizationStatus  clAuth= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if (clAuth ==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{

}
else
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIAlertView * aV= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Can't Get Location" message:@"Update your settings to allow location update. Isikota cannot work without user location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [aV show];
    }];
    return;
}
```

What it should be:
go straight here irrelevant of authorization status. Use authorization status to decide whether we should wait for updatelocation or not

```
   [BGLoadingView vPermaToastTillFinish:@"Getting Location" inView:
        [BGHelperForAllApplication window] doWhat:^{
        [self vStartUpdatingLocation];

        CLLocationHandler * clhHandler=[self singleton];//This one is a singleton anyway
        //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:clhHandler selector:@selector(vLocationFound) name:NotificationManageToGetCurrentLocation object:nil];
            CLAuthorizationStatus  clAuth= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
            PO(clhHandler.operation);
            if (clAuth ==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
            {
                [clhHandler haltThisThreadTillUnsuspended];//if not authorized then it'll never finish so don't bother halting
            }
            while (false);
    }];
```

Content of vStartUpdatingLocation

```
+(void) vStartUpdatingLocation
{
    while (false);
    AssertNonMainThread
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
        CLLocationHandler * singleton = [CLLocationHandler singleton];
        [singleton.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //This one pulls the alert
        PO(singleton.locationManager);
        while(false);
    }];
}
```